# Steam game share, how do I move my main pc?

Tags: steam, pc

I game shared with a couple of friends and it was all good on my old PC, but I got a new one and I am using my game share library when I play games.

How do I stop my PC from being in the shared library and my friends can play my games while I play other ones?

Comment: Isn't that specifically supposed to be impossible with family sharing?

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/240426/am-i-subject-to-any-disadvantages-when-sharing-steam-games/240427#240427

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have done something wrong. Please tell me if this is your scenario:

- Old PC Steam logged in as abc_user; bought many games and shared them
- New PC Steam logged in as xyz user; no games bought but abc_user shared to xyz_user

If this is what you did then you simply need to log into your new PC as abc_user and continue having control over your games.

Answer (score 1):

In steam family shared both (owner and the other) have to sign in into your new pc. If you have changed the pc, the new client you haved installed need to accept the old credentials.

So, you have to repeat the process, transfer your credentials to your friends and they have to do the same with you.

Ah, and other thing, if you are playing a game and your friend want to play with other game of your library that's imposible. Your friends only can play games of your library if you are not playing.

Answer (score 0):

This is not feasible. Steam Family Sharing is specifically designed so that if you, the primary owner of the library, are using a game you own, no one else is able to access your library. The only way around this I've discovered is to use Offline Mode so that one other person can use your library. However, this prevents you from most to all forms of multiplayer and prevents you from earning achievements or cards.

One thing to note, you and your friend can use each other's libraries at the same time. If you use a game in your friend's library that friend is still able to use your library.

Answer (score -1):

You may find some answers here : https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=3784-QLBM-5731